# Wpf Serialization Problem

Tags: c#, wpf, database, serialization, configuration

I am developing a big modular WPF application
one of these modules are widgets each widget has its own configuration that i can serialize
I want to serialize and save each user's configuration in database
but the problem is widgets configurations are different with different properties.
How can I save each widget configuration in on field of Database and retrive it when I want.

For more information I have a universal clock and the properties to serialize are Position, UtcTime, Name, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's a relational database, you will need to either create tables specific to each widget type (likely to be impractical, and harder to extend your system with new widgets) or store a blob of data per widget in either binary or text form (makes querying widget configuration more difficult, perhaps impossible).

As a side note, I wouldn't say this problem is WPF-related at all. It's more a serialization/extensibility/relational issue.

Comment: I can't do that because my app is extendible I want one solution for all widgets

Comment: @Navid: see the second option then. ie. a blob of data per widget.

Comment: @Navid: what do you mean? What XML?

Comment: Use Xml field in database and store the serialized data in that field

Comment: Absolutely. Like I said, whether you use binary or text is up to you. Point is, it will be a blob of data in one field rather than divided up into separate fields and easily queryable without resorting to proprietary extensions.